# Unable to open the downloaded File in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I should be able to download any type of file that I receive from the downstream application. Below is the code I tried. It is working for text and csv files, but the remaining types of files, like pdf, docx, png, etc., are not even opening.

Can you please correct the code if something is wrong with it? I will get the extension dynamically. Here in this code, just to try for pdf extension, I have hard-coded it.

Thanks in advance.

```java
public class downloadController {

    @Autowired
    DownloadService downloadService;

    @GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download() {
        return downloadService.download();
    }
}

public class DownloadService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download() {
        String response = restTemplate.exchange(......);
        String decodedResponse = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(response));
        Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(decodedResponse.getBytes());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                             .header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=\"report.pdf\"")
                             .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE))
                             .body(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String decodedResponse=new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(response));` - the internal structure of pdf is not text, so you are corrupting it by decoding it to a string. Depending on the exact response from the other application, most probably you just need to send the exact response as your own response, no decoding, no nothing.

Comment: @Chaosfire Wow Great. You are right. It is worked on after decoding the response and directly returning the byte[] as a response.